# Why does the compiler tell me the types are equal but can't cast them to each other? C++

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, stl

Context: I have a task to implement the Scene class and the Component class. The Component class is the base class for other components (ModComponent, EditComponent), and has a virtual function update(). The Scene class stores a std::list and has methods for adding/getting components from the list.

The syntax for getting a component should be something like this:

```cpp
scene_object.getComponent<TypeComponent>();
```

After searching the internet for a long time, I did this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>

class Component
{
    public:
        virtual void update()
        {
            std::cout << "BASE COMP" << std::endl;
        }
};

class ModComponent : public Component
{
    public:
        void update()
        {
            std::cout << "MOD COMP" << std::endl;
        }
};

class EditComponent : public Component
{
    public:
        void update()
        {
            std::cout << "EDIT COMP" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Scene
{
    public:
        template<class T>
        T getComponent()
        {
            for(auto& ptr : m_comps)
            {
                std::cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << std::endl;
                std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
                
                if(typeid(*ptr) == typeid(T))
                {
                    std::cout << "SAME TYPE" << std::endl;
                    //return *ptr;
                }
            }
        }

        template<class T>
        void addComponent(T obj)
        {
            m_comps.push_back(&obj);
        }

    private:
        std::list<Component*> m_comps;
};

int main()
{
    Component a;
    ModComponent b;
    EditComponent c;

    a.update();
    b.update();
    c.update();

    Scene sc;

    sc.addComponent(a);
    sc.addComponent(b);
    sc.addComponent(c);

    sc.getComponent<Component>.update();
    sc.getComponent<ModComponent>();
    sc.getComponent<EditComponent>().update();

    return 0;
}
```

Which in theory should work, because the lines:

```cpp
for(auto& ptr : m_comps)
{
    std::cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
                
    if(typeid(*ptr) == typeid(T))
    {
        std::cout << "SAME TYPE" << std::endl;
        //return *ptr;
    }
}
```

Tell me that the types are equal, but as soon as I uncomment the return, an error immediately occurs:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'T Scene::getComponent() [with T = ModComponent]':
<source>:82:24:   required from here
<source>:50:29: error: could not convert '* ptr' from 'Component' to 'ModComponent'
   50 |                     return *ptr;
      |                             ^~~
      |                             |
      |                             Component
```

Any corrections?

Comment: If you're absolutely sure of the type: `return *static_cast<ModComponent*>( ptr );` However ... what if it does not contain that type? You have UB. Also, the logic seems generally flawed here.

Comment: The type of `*ptr` is `Component`. It will never be the same as `ModComponent`. The `typeid` operator just isn't supposed to be used like that. Use `dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr)` to both check for compatibility and for conversion.

Comment: @user12002570 so, try uncomment calls for getComponent and you will see error

Comment: @IvanRekunov Make sure all paths inside the function have a return statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then how should the typeid be used if the typeid of both are equal?

Comment: Please make sure that the [mre] you show us is of the *failing* code, not something that works.

Comment: If `T` is `ModComponent` then `typeid(*ptr) == typeid(T)` will never be true, because they are just not the same type. You can't use it the way you want to or expect. You need to use some other way to solve your problem, and I mentioned one way.

Comment: @user12002570 your example doesn't work with other exemplars of object

Comment: @IvanRekunov Yup the point is that you should post exactly the code that reproduces the error and not the code that does not. That is, you should uncomment the said statements from your code in the question.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I will send you godbolt link and you will see that, they equals
https://godbolt.org/z/WTWsjxPKo

Comment: @ChrisMM if you say logic is flawed, then you should say how it is flawed

Comment: [It doesn't work for me](https://godbolt.org/z/rWzqx4qv6).

Comment: Oh your code is worse than I thought... Your `addComponent` function will save a pointer to a *local* variable. A variable which will go out of scope, and end its lifetime, when the function returns, The pointer you save will be invalid.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because you are doing completely different things, I gave you a link to godbolt where three compilers say that the types are equal

Comment: And we keep on saying that your example is flawed, because as clearly shown by my example the types are *not* equal. Even for inheritance, a new class creates a brand new type which is distinct and different from the base class. They types are *convertible* (from child to base only) but not the same.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why are you talking about things that have nothing to do with the question, without even running an example? Why were two other people able to run an example and try to help me, and you are trying to prove something to me?

Comment: The flaw in the example you linked to is this: `sc.getComponent<Component>()`. That will give you a `T` that is equal to `Component`. And `typeid(Component) == typeid(Component)` will be true, because they are indeed same type.

Comment: If you do `sc.getComponent<ModComponent>()` the comparison will fail, and your function will end without you returning anything. Which is another major flaw in your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so other T will be same. Please, run the example with commented return statement and you will see

Comment: Yes, `typeid(*ptr)` will be the same as `typeid(T)` ***only when `T` is a `Component`***, as it is in your example. If you try anything else it will fail.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/9qGaW17cn) I modified your own example slightly. As you can see, it no longer works as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable `ptr` in your `getComponent` method is of type `&Component`, so the compiler will complain, if you try to return `*ptr` (of type `Component`), since the method is suppose to return `T` (which can be of type `ModComponent`, `EditComponent`, etc.). You need to return value of declared return type or it's subtype.

If you are sure, that what you returning is indeed of type `T`, then you can return it after casting it:

```cpp
return *static_cast<ModComponent*>( ptr );
```

or (as suggested in comments) you can use `dynamic_cast` which is probably better suited for this:

```cpp
T* casted = dynamic_cast<T*>(ptr);
if (casted != NULL) {
    return *casted;
}
```

In both cases I would recommend you should return `T*` instead of `T` and also pass it as `T*` to the `addComponent` method. Obviously this will require additional changes to the behavior of the methods as well.

In first case dereferencing the object can be costly (because copy is made) and also any changes to the returned object will not be reflected to object stored in `Scene`. In `addComponent` you are taking the pointer to the local variable (parameter), so storing such pointer and using it later can result in undefined behaviour.